# Object Extraction and Construction

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am given the below image as input.
[image]

I want to remove the background and black cable from the image and keep only the red cable.
Also construct the red cable wherever it is hidden because of the black cable.

**NOTE : ONLY IMAGE PROCESSING TECHNIQUES ARE ALLOWED. NO ML OR DL IS ALLOWED.**

**In this case it is red wire that I want to extract but it can be some other colour too, so I want to generalize it.**

I guess construction can be done by dilation and erosion.

But please help me on how to extract this?

Comment: As long as the color is significantly different from the background, you can use cv2.inRange() either in BGR or HSV colorspace to threshold on just that color within some tolerance (min and max values)

Comment: You should provide some code of what you tried. This is not a website to solve your homework.

Answer (score 2):

To improve the results you have to play with morphological operations, also if the color of the cable is different you have to play with the code, **There is no General Solution**, except I can say that Deep Learning or Machine Learning may give better results.

- Edit: Thanks to @[fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7355741/fmw42) for mentioning `cv.inRange()`, I changed parts of the code to implement thresholding in HSV space.

[image: Results]

```
#========================
# Import Libraies
#========================
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cv2 as cv 

#------------------------
# Read Image
#========================
img = cv.imread("img.jpg")
imgHSV = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#------------------------
# Threshold Image
#========================
## mask of red
mask1 = cv.inRange(imgHSV, (0, 30, 0), (10, 255,255))
mask2 = cv.inRange(imgHSV, (170, 30, 0), (180, 255,255))

mask = cv.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)

mask = np.tile(mask, (3,1,1))
mask = np.swapaxes(mask , 0, 1)
mask  = np.swapaxes(mask , 1, 2)

print(mask.shape)

th1 = cv.bitwise_and(img,mask)

#------------------------
# Morphology
#========================
kernel1 = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.zeros((70,70),np.uint8)
kernel2[10:60, 10:60] = 1

img_opn = cv.morphologyEx(th1 ,cv.MORPH_OPEN ,kernel1)
img_cls = cv.morphologyEx(img_opn, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2)

#------------------------
# Results Visualization
#========================
plt.figure(num = "Red Cable")

plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(th1)
plt.title('Thresholded')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(img_opn)
plt.title('Opening')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(img_cls)
plt.title('Result')
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
#------------------------
#------------------------
```

Comment: color thresholding using cv2.inRange may do better than simple thresholding.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for your feedback, I'm just a beginner, I don't have a long experience using Open-CV so I will read about it and try to implement it.

Comment: You have to know the color first to use cv2.inRange().  If you have only one color wire and the rest of the image is grayscale, then you can convert to HSV color space and threshold on the saturation channel, since gray/black/white will be very low saturation and any colors will be higher saturation.

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if both the wires are of similar color?

Comment: @Ttpwaala If the colour was similar, then you have to look for another **discriminant feature**, it depends on the image, and on the object you want to segment.

Comment: For this [pic](https://objectextraction.blogspot.com/2020/10/blog-post.html). Certain pixels of ethernet is more white than certain pixels of USB cable. So, I am not able to come up with a proper solution. I request you to please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just look at every pixel and if the pixel isn't close to a red threshold remove it. You will have to understand RGB color representations.  This solution won't keep the white caps from your image.

Comment: I am sorry, but the wire can be of any colour.